# I'm using choropleth in plotly, but my map is not showing after plotting, only the bars show

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is my lines of code:

```
data=dict(type='choropleth',
         locations=df1['State Abv'],
         colorscale='rainbow',
         reversescale=True,
         z=df1['Voting-Age Population (VAP)'],
         locationmode='USA-states',
         text=df1['State'],
         marker=dict(line=dict(color='rgb(255,255,255)',width=2)),
         colorbar={'title':'Voting-Age Population per State'}
         )

layout=dict(title='2012_Election_Data',
       geo=dict(scope='usa',
        showlakes = True,
        lakecolor = 'rgb(85,173,240)'),
        )

choromap = go.Figure(data = [data],layout = layout)
iplot(choromap,validate=False)
```

[[enter image description here]https://1drv.ms/i/s!AjwLHMlCIc4_rDOxmR-WSy7i-qC2?e=lgfshX